# Saving a variable to a text file not working

Tags: python, discord.py

I have been trying to make a discord.py rewrite bot that sends a message containing currentyear (every day it shoudl go up by one) every day, however the text file does not update and it just keeps posting the same variable

```
async def yearpost():
  f = open("theyear.txt")
  currentyear = f.read()
  f.close
  message_channel = bot.get_channel(852955473802952774)
  await message_channel.send(currentyear)
  print(currentyear)
  currentyear + str(1)
  f = open("theyear.txt")
  f.write(currentyear)
  f.close
```

Comment: There are multiple typos. `f.close` needs to be `f.close()`, and more importantly for your problem here, `currentyear + str(1)` doesn't do anything since you don't assign the result back to a variable. You want `currentyear += 1` instead of `currentyear + str(1)`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate if I change it to ```currentyear += 1``` it causes the bot to spit out an error

```TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str```

Comment: Yes, you'd need to parse `currentyear` as a integer first using `int` before you can do math on it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate sorry im probably being extremely stupid right now but, how would I do that?

Comment: `currentyear = int(f.read())`. This will fail if `read` returns a non-number though, so you may want to handle that if there's any chance of that happening (although, that should likely never be the case). Then you need `f.write(str(currentyear))` at the end to convert it back to a string.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thank you, this worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open the file for write.

```
 f = open("theyear.txt", "w")
```